# no me funciona mi registro de usuario usando python y tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo un login y tengo una opción para registro.
Este registro tiene 3 campos una clave de administrador, un usuario y una contraseña
y el objetivo que que si no escribes correctamente la clave del administrador entonces el registro salga fallido pero cuando pulso el botón no se ejecuta y además me sale una ventana emergente que el registro es fallido sin siquiera pulsar el botón

```
def registrar():
   global pantalla2 
   pantalla2 = Toplevel(top)
   pantalla2.geometry("430x350+450+170")
   pantalla2.title("Registro")
   pantalla2.iconbitmap("nube.ico")
   
   global nombreusuario_entry
   global contrasenausuario_entry 
   nombreusuario_entry=StringVar()
   contrasenausuario_entry=StringVar()
   clave=StringVar()
   
   
   Label(pantalla2,text="Por favor ingrese un Usuario y Contraseña de su elección",fg="black",bg="DodgerBlue",width="400",height="2",font=("Calibri",13,"bold")).pack()
   Label (pantalla2, text="").pack()
   
   Label(pantalla2,text="ingrese la clave de seguridad").pack()
   insert_clave=Entry(pantalla2,textvariable=clave).pack()
   
   
   Label(pantalla2,text="Usuario",font=("Calibri",12,"bold")).pack()
   nombreusuario_entry = Entry(pantalla2)
   nombreusuario_entry.pack()
   Label(pantalla2).pack()

   Label(pantalla2,text="Contraseña",font=("Calibri",12,"bold")).pack()
   contrasenausuario_entry = Entry(pantalla2,show="*")
   contrasenausuario_entry.pack()
   
   Label(pantalla2).pack()

   Button(pantalla2,text="Registrar",bg="DodgerBlue",font=("Calibri",12,"bold"),command=insertar_datos(clave)).pack()

def insertar_datos(clave):

   if clave.get()=="1234":
       con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="", database="postulantebd")
       cur = con.cursor()
       sql= "INSERT INTO login (usuario,contrasena) values ('{0}','{1}')".format(nombreusuario_entry.get(),contrasenausuario_entry.get() )

       try:
           cur.execute(sql)
           con.commit()
           messagebox.showinfo(message="Registro Exitoso",title="Aviso")
           pantalla2.destroy() 

       except:
           con.rollback()
           messagebox.showinfo(message="Registro Fallido",title="Aviso")
   else:
       messagebox.showinfo(message="Registro Fallido",title="Aviso")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para pasarle un argumento a tu función que esta dentro de un botón puedes usar la función lambda de esta forma

```
Button(pantalla2,text="Registrar", command=lambda: insertar_datos(clave)).pack()
```

así la función será llamada cada vez que se presione el botón y no cada ves que se ejecute tu programa como te esta pasando

no he usado mysql pero si quieres hacer un insert prueba haciendolo de esta forma

```
sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("John", "Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

[MySql w3](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: me funcionó con lo del lambda, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esto tiene que ver con la ejecución del método pack() luego de la definición del widget. Separa la definición de la gestión de la geometría en dos líneas:

entNombre = Entry()
entnombre.pack()

Cuando van en la misma línea pueden presentar problemas (en concreto, cuando el widget puede retornar valores). Como buena práctica, mantenlos siempre separados para evitar problemas.